# Openfeint Achievment Progress on Android

Tags: android, openfeint, achievements

My team has decided to integrate OpenFeint into the app we are developing to leverage the achievements API.. We currently track the achievement progress locally on the phone, and submit the achievement once we detect that it has been fulfilled.

I've seen other OF apps update achievement progress though - such that the user can see a percentage. We would like to do this as well, but I can not find any documentation on how to do this in Android.

Also, we have considered the case where the user uninstalls the app from their phone/gets a new phone/etc.. Is there a way to get the current achievement progress for some user from OpenFeint's servers? If so, we could use these values to aggregate achievement progress, and avoid issues that are caused from the above scenarios.

thanks for any insight..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think OpenFeint currently supports incremental achievements on Android (they do on iOS however, which may be where some of the confusion is coming in).  As for migrating the achievement progress:  If the user logs in with the same username/password on the new phone, their progress should be transferred over automatically.

You can also check out [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com/achievements), which provides a very similar achievement system (maybe even better).

Comment: Yes, that is clear to me now as well. You can't increment the achievement but you can set it's completion to some percentage.

Answer (score 1):

you can call `UpdateAchievement(int achievementID, float percentage, bool showNotification)` to save achivment progress, but it isn't incremental